# Python - Concat variable output to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I am trying to concat output of a sql output to a string as below:

```
dwh_cur.execute("""select name from sales where id = 123""")
name = dwh_cur.fetchone()[0]
a = print(name)
b = str(a) + " is the name of the agent"
print(b)
```

The above returns

```
None is the name of the agent
```

Expected output:

```
Steve is the name of the agent
```

Comment: Remove `a = `, i.e.: `print(name);
b =  f"{name} is the name of the agent"`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = print(name)
```

returns None

Try:

```
b = "{} is the name of the agent".format(name)
```

Comment: The `str(name)` part is useless - `name` is already a string. And this would better be done using string formatting, ie `b = "{} is the name of the agent".format(name)`

Comment: yes you're right. i just copied the line from him and changed 'a' to 'name' to make it work for him :)

Comment: But it's not too late to edit your post ;) (SO is not only about "making it work", it's also about "making it right").

Comment: true, i edieted my post !